# gets() not asking for input unless getchar() or another gets() is used before it

Tags: c, string, newline, fgets, gets

i made a c source file 'functions.c' which contains some functions, a header file 'functions.h' containing prototypes of the functions, and a 'main.c' source file. Now i am using main to call functions in functions.c using the prototypes in functions.h. Below is a function from 'functions.c' file.

my code:

```
#include "functions.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void func1(void)
{
  int i, j, k, l;
  char string[25];
  printf("Enter any valid 10 digit mobile number\n");
  here:
  //getchar();
  gets(string);

  j = k = 0;
  for (i = 0; string[i] != '\0';)
  {
    if (string[i] <= 57 && string[i] >= 48)
      i++;
    else if (string[i] == 45 || string[i] == 46 || string[i] == 47 || string[i] == 42 || string[i] == 95 || string[i] == 124 || string[i] == 58 || string[i] == 92 || string[i] == 59 || string[i] == 0)
    {
      i++;
      k++;
    } //some special characters allowed
    else
    {
      printf("%c is not a valid digit or symbol for a mobile number\n", string[i]);
      j++;
      i++;
    }
  }
  if ((i - k) == 10 && j == 0)
    printf("Mobile number is valid\n");
  if ((i - k) != 10 || j != 0)
  {
    printf("Mobile number is invalid\nEnter 1 to try again or 2 to exit\n");
    scanf("%d", &l);
    if (l == 1)
    {
      printf("Enter mobile number again\n");
      goto here;
    }
    else if (l == 2)
      printf("Program Terminating\n");
    else
      printf("You didn't enter either of 1 or 2\nProgram Terminating\n");
  }
}
```

Now my questions are -

1-"Why is gets() not working? Why is gets() not asking for any input?"

2-"Why does it start asking for input when i include getchar() in the code? I mean when i remove the comment sign from the getchar()?"

I am a newbie.. so please go soft.. thanks for answers.

Comment: the issue will be due to undefined behaviour ( UB ) invoked by other parts of your code. please post your code

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and edit your question to include that. Also include input and actual and expected output.

Comment: Also, don't use `gets`, it is dangerous, have been deprecated since the C99 standard, and in the C11 standard was actually removed.

Comment: okay.. i am editing it

Comment: should post a complete compileable program - including main.c and functions.h

Comment: as i mentioned, main is in main.c source file.. and i am calling func1() from it..

Comment: @PrabhavPandya most likely you are not emptying the `stdin` buffer before calling `gets` so what code is executed before is relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your mixed use of `scanf` and `gets`: When you use `scanf` to read a number, the newline the user presses will be in the input buffer, and the `scanf` call will not remove it. However when you loop back to call `gets` (by the way, don't use labels and `goto` for loops!) the `gets` call reads that newline and sees it as an empty line.

After `scanf` you should read characters in a loop until you have read the newline.

---

Important note: You might see some places that uses `fflush(stdin)` to "flush" the input buffer (i.e. discard all to (and including) the newline). This is technically *undefined behavior* according to the C specification. Some environments have it as an extension, but if you want to be correct and portable you should not use it.

Comment: I understand what you said for the case when command goes back above through `goto`.. but what about the case when `gets` is executed for the first time, i.e. no `scanf` is used before it yet? `stdin` has no newline character waiting in this case?

Comment: @PrabhavPandya If you haven't done any input before calling `gets` then it should work as expected. But your code is in a separate function, we don't know what you do before you call this function, like for example use `scanf` there too?

Answer (score 1):

`gets(string)` reads from the standart input buffer `stdin`. If you use `scanf()` at any other point in the program, the newline character (`'\n'`) the user pressed to submit the `scanf` input will still be in `stdin` unless you manually clear it. `gets(string)` will then interpret that as an empty line.

Your solution is either not to make mixed use of `scanf` and `gets` or to manually clear the input buffer `stdin` after every call of `scanf` or similar functions.